# Shorten jQuery if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we improve following `if-else` code:

```
$(".rdo_confirm").change(function(){  
    if($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#btn_save").attr("disabled",false);
    } else {
        $("#btn_save").attr("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Comment: try `$("#btn_save").attr("disabled",$(this).val() == "Y");`

Comment: You should [use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` for the `disabled` property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 12):

You could use the check for the value directly, as it returns a boolean

```
$(".rdo_confirm").on('change', function(){  
    $("#btn_save").prop("disabled", this.value !== "Y");
});
```

The check for `$(this).val() == "Y"` returns either `true` or `false`.
It seems you want to pass `false` if the check returns `true`, meaning you just negate the check.
Using native javascript it turns out to be something like  `this.value !== "Y"`.
As `disabled` is a property, you also want to use `prop()`

Answer (score 1):

**You can compress this conditional code into 1 Line of code into two ways, Have a look:**

**By using ternary operator:**

```
$(".rdo_confirm").change(function(){  

$(this).val() == "Y")? $("#btn_save").attr("disabled",false):$("#btn_save").attr("disabled",true);

});
```

**OR**

**By using simple condition:**

```
$(".rdo_confirm").change(function(){  
var cond=(this.value !== "Y");
$(this).val() == "Y")? $("#btn_save").attr("disabled",cond);
```

Comment: Do *not* use a ternary operator in order to induce side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".rdo_confirm").on('change',function(){  
   $("#btn_save").prop("disabled",!($(this).val()=="Y"));
});
$("#btn_save").on('click',function(){  
   alert("test");
});
```

```css
span{
padding-right:20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rdo_confirm" type="radio" name="rdo_confirm" value="Y"/><span>Yes</span>
<input class="rdo_confirm" type="radio" name="rdo_confirm" value="N"/><span>No</span>
<input id="btn_save" type="button"  value="Click"/>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what improvement you have done in OP code?

Comment: Firstly, code only answers are useless. The idea of this site is to educate, which simply dumping code does not do. Secondly, how does this achieve the goal of making the code shorter? It's *longer* than the original. Lastly, @adeneo already nailed this one 10 minutes before you even answered...